# platform for Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there is any platform available in the market for SQLite, which basically makes it easy to manage databases?

Something like Eclipse for Android, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you meant by platform was an IDE, then there's this thing called [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/) that you may want to take a look at. It's something that is more like workbench or phpMyAdmin for MySQL. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) if you're using Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

you can get from here  http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/